# Too many threads using "cling UPnP library"

Tags: android, multithreading, upnp, cling

I'm using Fabric / Crashlytics to track my app crashes and I have this crash:

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: thread creation failed at
>   java.lang.VMThread.create(VMThread.java) at
>   java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1050) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:913)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.processWorkerExit(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:962)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1098)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

I see 1230 threads, of which 1170 are from cling UPnP library, like this:

> cling-1761 at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java) at
>   java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364) at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpExchange.waitForDone(HttpExchange.java:170)
>   at
>   org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.jetty.StreamClientImpl$2.call(StreamClientImpl.java:115)
>   at
>   org.fourthline.cling.transport.impl.jetty.StreamClientImpl$2.call(StreamClientImpl.java:108)
>   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Any idea why this librery is using too many threads? I think that I fix this problem I have not more crashes related with thread creation.

Thanks

Comment: Using Cling while DMR playback it has to poll and check property like duration and wait for stop command etc.so it creates in particular time interval which you can optimize.

Answer (score 0):

When you init an UpnpServiceImpl, you can create your configuration to set the thread pool size. The example code is:

```
    protected UpnpServiceConfiguration createConfiguration() {
    return new AndroidUpnpServiceConfiguration() {
        protected ExecutorService createDefaultExecutorService() {
            return new ThreadPoolExecutor(10,
                    60,
                    60L,
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                    new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(),
                    new ClingThreadFactory(),
                    new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());
        }

        @Override
        public int getRegistryMaintenanceIntervalMillis() {
            return 5000;
        }
    };
}
```